# Discount calculator

Tags: calculator, pascal

Good day, I am new to programming and im trying my hand at a discount calculator that is written in pascal. Sadly i am having some issues. I am posting my code and i am hoping you all could point out where i went wrong.

```
program Discount_Calulator;
    {Name: Yohan Henry}
    {Date: 28.02.2014}
    {Purpose:To accept the customer name and total payment then calculate the discount given to the customer then finally print the customer's name, customer's total payment, customer's discount, customer's after discount price and total discount}

    Var
    Total_discount: real;
    [Y]: integer;                            {Here I listed all my variables I needed to make the program}
    After_discount Array [1.20]: real;
    Establishment Array [1.20]: real;
    Total_payment Array [1.20]: real;
    Discount Array [1.20]: real;

    Begin
    start
    clscr;
    Total Discount := 0;
    FOR Y := 1 to 20 DO
    After_discount [Y] := 0;                     {Here Initialized my variables to make it easier to run}
    Total_payment [Y] := 0;
    Discount [y] ;= 0;
    END FOR

    FOR [Y] := 1 to 20 DO
    writeln 'Enter Customer Name';
    readln 'Establishment [Y]';
    writeln 'Enter the Customer's Total Payment';
    reanln 'Total_payment [Y]';
    END FOR

    FOR [Y] := 1 to 20 DO
    IF Total_payment [Y] >= 15000 THEN
    Discount [Y] := Total_payment [Y] * 0.10;
    END IF

    IF Total_payment [Y] >= 12500 AND
    Total_payment [Y] < 15000 THEN
    Discount [Y] := Total_payment [Y] * 0.05
    END IF

    IF Total_payment  [Y] > 10500 AND
    Total_payment [Y] < 12500 THEN
    Discount [Y] := Total_payment [Y] * 0.02
    END IF

    After_discount [Y] := Total_payment [Y] - Discount [Y]
    Total_discount [Y] := Total_discount [Y] + Discount [Y]
    END FOR [Y] := 1;

    WHILE [Y] <= 20 DO
    WHILE LOOP TO PRINT
    writeln 'The Customer Name is Establishment [Y]'
    writeln  'The Total_payment of the Customer is $x', Total_payment [Y]'
    writeln  'The Customer Discount is $x', Discount [Y]'
    writeln  'The Customer Price after Discount is $x', After_discount [Y]'
    Y := Y + 1
    writeln  'The Total Overall Discount is $x', Total_discount [Y]
    END.
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Are you getting unexpected results?

Comment: nope the program just isnt running

Comment: For example... Array [1.20]: real; should be [1..20] and maybe i see some other syntax errors.

Answer (score -1):

I spotted one: Around where you say "{Here Initialized my variables to make it easier to run}",  `Discount [y] ;= 0;` must be `Discount [y] := 0;`. I can imagine that the error message is not clear on that kind of syntax error.

And then I spotted a "reanln" ("readln"?). If this is the original code you tried to translate the compiler probably complained.